# Syntax errors in Pluscal code for BayerMoore algorithm

Tags: tla+, pluscal

I attempted to port the BayerMoore algorithm for finding patterns in
strings using the TLA<sup>+</sup> toolkit. My main question is about the
syntax. I think this error is thrown by these lines as the character to ASCII
conversion isn't automatic. This conversion is also required in the rest of
the code. How can I fix this ? Can I also ask if there is a way to execute
the code to test just once without simulating using the model checker ?

```
  p := in_pattern[i];
  flag[ p ] := 1;
```

I understand that the state space here is enormous. So I just simulate now but that doesn't seem to complete either.

> : Attempted to apply function: ( 0 :> -1 @@   1 :> -1 @@   2 :> -1 @@
> 3 :> -1 @@   4 :> -1 @@   -----   ----- to argument "T", which is not
> in the domain of the function.

This is the pluscal code. It is written in an imperative style as I am still learning
TLA<sup>+</sup>

```
EXTENDS Integers, Sequences,Naturals, TLC

Max(x,y) == IF x < y THEN y ELSE x


(*--algorithm bayermoore
variables
           i,m,l,n,j,k,p,skips,
           flag \in [0 .. 256 -> -1 .. -1],
           in_pattern = <<"T", "E", "S", "T">>,
           in_text = <<"N", "T", "E", "S", "T", "E", "E", "D">>;
 
begin
 i := 0;          

 while i < Len(in_pattern) do
  i := i + 1;
  p := in_pattern[i];
  flag[ p ] := 1;
 end while;
 
 

m := Len(in_pattern); n := Len(in_text); j := m - 1; k := n - m;
 while j <= k do
  skips := 0;
     l := m - 1;
     while j >= 0 do
        if in_text[j] # in_text[i + j]
            then
            skips := Max(1,j - flag[in_text[i+j]]);
            skip;
            else
            j :=  j - 1;
        end if
     end while;
     if skips = 0
        then
        print i;
     end if
 end while;
 end algorithm; *)
```

I believe the loops will work but that isn't fully tested.

The Java code that works is this.

```
public class BoyerMoore {

    int R = 256;
    String pattern = "TEST";
    String text = "MYFUNNYONLINETESTCANSUCCEEDORNOT";
    int[] right = new int[256];
    public BoyerMoore(){
        for(int i = 0 ; i < R ; i++){
            right[i] = -1;
        }
        for( int i = 0 ; i < pattern.length() ; i ++ ){
            right[pattern.charAt(i)] = i;
        }
    }

    public int search(){
        int m = pattern.length();
        int n = text.length();
        int skip;

        for(int i = 0 ; i <= n - m ; i += skip){
            skip = 0;
            for( int j = m - 1 ; j >= 0 ;j --){
                if( pattern.charAt(j) != text.charAt(i+j)){
                    skip = Math.max(1,j - right[text.charAt(i+j)]);
                    break;
                }
            }
            if( skip == 0 ) return i;
        }
        return n;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This helped me understand how to use the TLA<sup>+</sup> toolkit and execute the TLC Model checker even though the **spec./code may have a bug**.

But mainly I used

> struct == [a |-> 97, b |-> 98, c |-> 99]

and a subset of values in the TLA Toolkit configuration section.

This section

> ```
> CONSTANTS Character, text, pattern
> ASSUME text \in Seq(Character)
> ASSUME pattern \in Seq(Character)
> ```

uses the configured values when the model checker executes.

So now the state space is small. This was suggested to me by Stephan Merz when I asked the TLA<sup>+</sup> Google group.

I tried a few methods and eventually set it up like this in the toolkit.
[image]
The original function that I was looking for is this.

```
Ascii(char) == 96 + CHOOSE z \in 1 .. 26 :"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"[z] = char
```

But this throws an [error](https://github.com/tlaplus/tlaplus/issues/512)

```
----------------------------- MODULE bayermoore -----------------------------
EXTENDS Integers, Sequences,Naturals, TLC
CONSTANTS Character, text, pattern
ASSUME text \in Seq(Character)
ASSUME pattern \in Seq(Character)
Max(x,y) == IF x < y THEN y ELSE x
struct == [a |-> 97, b |-> 98, c |-> 99]
(*--algorithm bayermoore

variables
           i,m,l,n,j,k,p,skips,x,y,
           flag = [g \in 0..256 |-> -1];

begin
 i := 1;          

 while i < Len(pattern) do
  p := struct[pattern[i]];
  flag[p] := 1;
  i := i + 1;
 end while;
 
 
i := 1;          
m := Len(pattern);
n := Len(text); 
k := n - m;
 while i <= k do
  skips := 0;
     j := m - 1;
     while j >= 0 do
            x := struct[pattern[j+1]];
            y := struct[text[i + j]];
            \* print ( "x " \o ToString(x) \o "y " \o ToString(y) );
            print ( "i " \o ToString(i) \o " j " \o ToString(j));
        if x # y then
            skips := Max(1,j - flag[y]);
            j := -1;
        end if;
        j :=  j - 1;
     end while;
  i := i + skips;  
  print ("i - " \o ToString(i)); 
 end while;
 end algorithm; *)
```